# What do all those permissions mean?

Tags: file-permissions

[image]

Where can I find out the meaning?

Comment: It is Unix file system permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r = read
w = write
x = execute
```

[image: permissions]

1st block of rwx is for owner
2nd block for group
3rd for public